# Allow suggested edits always

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

When I hit 2000+ reputation, I can no longer suggest edits.

It seems to be the general view that forced edits are strictly better (for the editor) than suggested edits, and as such once you can do it, you no longer need to suggest.

I disagree. I've had times where I've wanted to make a significant change to a question, but would rather run the edit by the asker first in case I was actually out to lunch on what the asker wanted.

What would be the downside of adding a "Make this edit a suggestion" button when making an edit? I don't care about the 2 rep either, just the ability to suggest.

Comment: I assume you would want the suggestion made only to the post OP, not the normal 'any 2/3 2k users'?

Comment: Edits (suggested or otherwise) can always be rolled back. You can comment to the OP asking if the edits were OK.

Comment: If you want to run an edit by the OP, post a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever I make extensive edits to a post, particularly where it concerns the OP's language and an interpretation of what I think he's trying to say, I leave a comment along the lines of

> I have significantly revised your post. I think it still says what you intended to say, but could you please make sure it does? If it doesn't, by all means feel free to roll my edits back.

I have yet to have an OP come back and tell me I was completely off, but it's a nice way to have a second check as someone with full edit privileges.

If it concerns code in answers or something I really am not sure about, I'd just comment and leave it at that.

Answer (score 4):

You could make your edit suggestion anonymously.

However, this does not necessarily mean your answer is seen by the OP; it will be seen by 2 or 3 reviewers, depending on the SE site it is on. The OP does have a binding vote, as usual.

On Stack Overflow, we have a problem with people not reviewing suggested edits properly (robo-reviewers). This means an edit is often approved before the OP got to see it.

So, it would be better to use a comment to ask the OP for clarification.

Comment: Good point about the whole robo-reviewing mess.